# How to redirect from a new post url to the show post url in Buffalo

Tags: go, buffalo

I am building a blog website in Buffalo, and I'm running into a bit of an issue. I have the following routes in `app.go`:

```
b := BlogsResource{}
blogGroup := app.Group("/blog")
blogGroup.GET("/", b.List)
blogGroup.GET("/new", b.New)
blogGroup.GET("/post/{slug}", b.Show)
blogGroup.GET("/post/{slug}/edit", b.Edit)
blogGroup.POST("/", b.Create)
blogGroup.PUT("/post/{slug}", b.Update)
blogGroup.DELETE("/post/{slug}", b.Destroy)
blogGroup.Middleware.Skip(Authorize, b.List, b.Show)
```

And my `blogs.go` resource create method looks like this:

```
func (v BlogsResource) Create(c buffalo.Context) error {
    // Allocate an empty Blog
    blog := &models.Blog{}

    // Bind blog to the html form elements
    if err := c.Bind(blog); err != nil {
        return errors.WithStack(err)
    }

    // Get the DB connection from the context and validate it
    tx := c.Value("tx").(*pop.Connection)
    verrs, err := blog.Create(tx)

    if err != nil {
        return errors.WithStack(err)
    }

    if verrs.HasAny() {
        // Make the errors available inside the html template
        c.Set("errors", verrs)

        // Render again the new.html template that the user can
        // correct the input.
        return c.Render(422, r.Auto(c, blog))
    }

    // If there are no errors set a success message
    c.Flash().Add("success", T.Translate(c, "blog.created.success"))
    // and redirect to the blogs index page
    return c.Redirect(302, "blogPostPath()", render.Data{"slug": blog.Slug})
}
```

The `new.html` looks like this:

```
<div class="page-header">
<h1>New Blog</h1>
</div>

<%= form_for(blog, {action: blogPath(), method: "POST"}) { %>
<%= partial("blogs/form.html") %>
<a href="<%= blogPath() %>" class="btn btn-warning" data-confirm="Are you sure?">Cancel</a>
<% } %>
```

The problem I'm running into is when I try to do the redirect, it is pointing to the correct url `localhost:3000/blog/post/my-blog-post-here`, but the body is trying to use the `blogs/index.html` template instead of the `blogs/show.html`. So, what do I need to do to have the redirect point to the correct URL and contain the right body? I've tried setting the `<%= form_for(blog, {action: blogPath(), method: "POST"}) { %>` to `<%= form_for(blog, {action: blogPostPath(), method: "POST"}) { %>` in the `new.html`, but I get an error where I need the slug when going to `localhost:3000/blog/new`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a routing issue.
I stumbled on this kind of issue.
It was related to the order of the routes delcaration.
The router is order sensitive; it will route to the first matching declaration...
Maybe in your case the first route that matches is "/"
I am not 100% sure, but try the other way round for ex :

blogGroup.GET("/post/{slug}", b.Show)

blogGroup.GET("/post/{slug}/edit", b.Edit)

blogGroup.GET("/", b.List)
blogGroup.GET("/new", b.New)